# Plot only 5 of 7 factor levels in R

Tags: r, plot

Alright, this is probably so easy that no-one wrote it up (or I can't find it):

I have a variable with 7 factors:

```
[1] "NICHT ERHOBEN"        "STIMME VOLL ZU"       "STIMME EHER ZU"       "STIMME EHER NICHT ZU"
[5] "STIMME GAR NICHT ZU"  "WEISS NICHT"          "KEINE ANGABE"
```

I would like to plot the variable with plot(df$v1, df$v_with_factors), and R does it just fine.

How do I omit the first ("nicht erhoben") and the last ("keine angabe") factor when plotting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's an annoyingly awkward  but quite common task -but you can use `droplevels`

```
> DF= data.frame(nums=1:8, facs=as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D")))
  nums facs
1    1    A
2    2    A
3    3    B
4    4    B
5    5    C
6    6    C
7    7    D
8    8    D
```

heres the way with blank spaces:

```
> with(DF[which(DF$facs!="A"),], plot(facs, nums))
```

[image]

```
> with(droplevels(DF[which(DF$facs!="A"),]), plot(facs, nums))
```

here it is after you `droplevels` :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do a subset of your data before plotting: subdata <- subset(df$v1, condition)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how exactly your data looks like the solution is likely to be the following (I do not have access to R right at the moment to test, but the approach should be fine):

```
# Indices of all levels of the factor that you want to plot
lindex = which(!(levels(df$v_with_factors) %in% c("NICHT ERHOBEN", "KEINE ANGABE")))
# Indices of all data records that correspond to the selected levels of the factor
index = df$v_with_factors@.Data %in% lindex

plot(df$v1[index], df$v_with_factors[index])
```

Comment: this worked, thank you! Stephen's version worked a little bit better (still prints the yaxlabels), so I'm accepting his answer, but yours worked as well :) Thanks again!